# How to create a pool of buffers from the GMFBridgeController Sink Filter with DirectShow.Net

Tags: c#, directshow.net

In the GMFBridge documentation under "Looser Coupling", it states that it is possible to create a pool of buffers from the Sink Filter.  How???  I am somewhat new to DirectShow and am using DirectShow.Net library and am able to create a filtergraph and use an InfTee filter to Sink with the bridge. But this causes a deadlock since I am trying to use three different source graphs. I have been looking online everywhere for an example of how to create a pool of buffers so I may render a sink filter that is not tied to the other buffers.  Can someone please help me with this, and if possible can you include an example to I can see it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out a different solution to my issue here. It was to use the original FilterGraph to implement the SampleGrabber, Preview, and WebStream.  But for the recording of the video I was able to create an new FilterGraph that would use the WebStream as the source filter and then record with a WM Asf Writer.